# Citing two papers by the same author consecutively

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, lyx, natbib

Under biblatex, what I am doing is this

```
\citealt*[2019]{suarez2018unintended}
```

My purpose is to display something that looks like on pdf as

```
Suarez Serrato 2018, 2019
```

So that I don't have redundancies.

But it looks like this

[image]

Why is there a weird "p."? And I want to make the hyperlink to be applied to 2019, too. No need for "2018" and "2019" to have a separate hyperlink although that's also fine.

Alternatively, if I do

```
\citealt*{suarez2018unintended,suarez2019testtesttest}
```

then the pdf output looks like

[image]

I want to abbreviate to

```
Suarez Serrato 2018, 2019
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set the tags `natbib` and `bibtex`, I will assume that you're interested in a natbib/bibtex-based solution. If that's the case, I suggest you employ the `\citealt` macro (provided by the `natbib` package) to achieve your formatting objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{s18,author = "Suarez Serrato, J.", title = "Initial Thoughts", year = 2018}
@misc{s19,author = "Suarez Serrato, J.", title = "Further Thoughts", year = 2019}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable style
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citealt{s18,s19}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saved your code as tex file. Imported it to lyx. Created mybib.bib separately. I cannot replicate your result.. "I found no \bibstyle command" That's what Lyx says.

Comment: On Overleaf, it was successfully replicated. I can't figure out how to make it happen on Lyx.

Comment: @user1849133 - I'm afraid I can't help you with `lyx` as I've never used it. Very sorry.

Comment: @user1849133 - About migrating the code above to lyx: All I can suggest is that you post a new query to this cite and ask for help on how to migrate or port the code to lyx.

Answer (score 0):

The optional postnote argument to `biblatex` cite commands like the `2019` in

```
\citealt*[2019]{suarez2018unintended}
```

is supposed to be a short note added after the citation label. Often/usually it contains a pinpoint reference to a particular page. That's why you get

> Suárez Serrato 2018, p. 2019

the `2019` is interpreted as a page reference.

If you want more compact citations in `biblatex`, you need to switch from the `authoryear` to the `authoryear-comp` style. Just list all works in the same pair of braces to the relevant `\...cite...` command.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Knuth 1984, 1986)]